# Python vs MATLAB for interpolation

Tags: python, matlab, interpolation

I want to leave MATLAB for full python integration in my scripts, and I realised that doing the same interpolation with the same values does not produce the same result on both languages! I am pretty sure the matlab code was correct so I am wondering if what I did on python is the same.

The MATLAB code is:

```
F = TriScatteredInterp( xPanel', yPanel', COPEN', 'natural' );
toolCOPEN = F( xTool', yTool' );
toolCOPEN( isnan( toolCOPEN ) ) = (-1)
```

which happens to be a one line code with griddata:

```
toolCOPEN = griddata( ( xPanel, yPanel ),
                      COPEN,
                      ( xTool, yTool ),
                      method = 'linear',
                      fill_value = '-1'
                      )
```

The final toolCOPEN differs and I am really wondering why..? I would guess they both use Delaunay Triangulation which should produce the same results...

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `natural` neighbor interpolation in Matlab, but a `linear` interpolation in Python, which likely causes differences in the results.

Comment: I thought there were the same ..! I did not find a natural neighbour interpolation in Python ; do you know if it already exists?